# How to open modal Fancybox after wpforms submit?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Help me please

I have a simple WPForms form with two text REQUIRED fields
And I need open modal Fancybox ONLY after WPforms successful submit

```
function openFormResp() {
 new Fancybox([
    {
       src: '#modal-response',
       type: 'inline',
    },
 ])
}

document.querySelectorAll('form').forEach(form => {
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
          openFormResp()
    })
})
```

this code does not work properly because when the fields have not passed validation the modal window opens! And it should be opened only after validation!

Comment: If you are talking about HTML5 form validation here (`required` attribute on the input fields, and not something WPForms "validates" by its own logic), then you can simply check if the form is valid - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//-----MODAL RESPONSE------------------------------------------
function openFormResp() {
    new Fancybox([
        {
            src: '#modal-response',
            type: 'inline',
        },
    ])
}
//-----WPFORMS ACTION AFTER SUBMIT------------------------------------------
(($) => {
    $('form.wpforms-form').on('wpformsAjaxSubmitSuccess', (e) => {
        openFormResp()
    })
})(jQuery)
```